# Undeclared identifier 'balances'

Tags: contract-development

How do I fix the undeclared identifier `balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000000000000000000000;`  in the below code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Token {

    /// @return total amount of tokens
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply) {}

    /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
    /// @return The balance
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
    /// @param _from The address of the sender
    /// @param _to The address of the recipient
    /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
    /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
    /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

    /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
    /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
    /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {}

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}

contract StandardToken {

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
        //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
        //Replace the if with this one instead.
        //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        //same as above. Replace this line with the following if you want to protect against wrapping uints.
        //if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        approve(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
      return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
}

contract NMR { // CHANGE THIS. Update the contract name.

    /* Public variables of the token */

    /*
    NOTE:
    The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
    They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
    Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
    */
    string public name;                   // Token Name
    uint8 public decimals;                // How many decimals to show. To be standard complicant keep it 18
    string public symbol;                 // An identifier: eg SBX, XPR etc..
    string public version = 'H1.0'; 
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;     // How many units of your coin can be bought by 1 ETH?
    uint256 public totalEthInWei;         // WEI is the smallest unit of ETH (the equivalent of cent in USD or satoshi in BTC). We'll store the total ETH raised via our ICO here.  
    address public fundsWallet;           // Where should the raised ETH go?



    // This is a constructor function 
    // which means the following function name has to match the contract name declared above
    function NMRToken() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000000000000000000000;    // Give the creator all initial tokens. This is set to 1000 for example. If you want your initial tokens to be X and your decimal is 5, set this value to X * 100000. (CHANGE THIS)
        totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000000;                        // Update total supply (1000 for example) (CHANGE THIS)
        name = "NMRToken";                                   // Set the name for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        decimals = 18;                                               // Amount of decimals for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        symbol = "NMR";                                             // Set the symbol for display purposes (CHANGE THIS)
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 10000;                                      // Set the price of your token for the ICO (CHANGE THIS)
        fundsWallet = msg.sender;                                    // The owner of the contract gets ETH
    }

    function() payable{
        totalEthInWei = totalEthInWei + msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        require(balances[fundsWallet] >= amount);

        balances[fundsWallet] = balances[fundsWallet] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + amount;

        Transfer(fundsWallet, msg.sender, amount); // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

        //Transfer ether to fundsWallet
        fundsWallet.transfer(msg.value);                               
    }

    /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
        //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
        //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
        if(!_spender.call(bytes4(bytes32(sha3("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)) { require; }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `contract NMR` to `contract NMR is StandardToken`.

Comment: Great, that worked for that but now I get this error: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
function NMRToken () {
^------^ . Do I have the wrong function name?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting the error in (at least) `StandardToken` contract? That contract does not have such variable. You should probably inherit from some other basic token contract - none of the ones you showed declare such an identifier, so it's difficult to say what you should inherit.

Comment: Ok, can you answer one more question regarding the above contract? where does the token contract stop and the crowdsale contract start?

Comment: The only thing that looks like crowdsale is the `payable` function in the last contract. But it's very badly mixed up inside a token contract.

Answer (score 0):

> **Men**: please stop to build contracts “inheriting” contracts that you are not able to write by yourself. You MUST be in control with your code, not trying and asking until it works!

If the compiler says you that some element you are using is not declared, this means exactly that it is not declared or that it is declared with some minor spelling differences (“balance” instead of “balances” and so on) or that it is declared outside the scope of the code fragment.

What you have to do is:

1) inspect your code and find the declaration
2) if it exists, check the spelling
3) if it exists and the spelling is ok, check if it is visible for the code fragment which yields error
4) if it does not exist, declare it

Full stop. Nothing simpler.

In this case

```
    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
```

Is declared in StandardToken, but you do not inherit it. So it is outside the scope of the code fragment!

What is the reason for having two virtual contract here? They are leaved alone...

Please check operator “is” in Solidity documentation.